# Removing seasonality and trend for forecasting with tree based models

Tags: time-series, cart, seasonality, supervised-learning, trend

I am working on a problem where I'm using tree-based models (RFs, GBTs) for forecasting. I've read that I have to de-trend the data if I'm using a tree-based model, however, I am reading conflicting opinions on whether or not to remove the seasonality as well. What is the correct answer?